# VBA: Set Workbook, and Activate Workbook Error

Tags: vba, excel

There is a simple task that I cannot figure out. I would like to Copy Value of wb1.ws1 and paste into wb2.ws2

This is what I have tried.

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet

'Open wb1 and ws1 and set
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("R:\Workbook1.xlsx")
Set ws1 = Sheet("Sheet1")

'Open wb2 and ws2 and set
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\Workbook2.xlsx")
Set ws2 = Sheet("Sheet2")

'Copy Value of wb1.ws1 and paste into wb2.ws2
wb1.ws1.Range("A1").Copy wb2.ws2.Range("A1")
```

Why does this not work? It seems like I cannot select a range by specifying wb1.ws1.Range(XYZ)

It forces me to separate the lines into

```
wb1.Activate
ws1.Select
Range("A1").Copy
wb2.Activate
ws2.Select
Range("A1").Paste
```

Seems terribly inefficient but I don't know how to eliminate the Activate-Select nightmare

Answer (score 1):

Once you set a worksheet the workbook parent is already defined.  so declare the parent at the `Set`

```
Dim wb1 as Workbook, wb2 as Workbook
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet

'Open wb1 and ws1 and set
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open("R:\Workbook1.xlsx")
Set ws1 = wb1.WorkSheets("Sheet1")

'Open wb2 and ws2 and set
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open("R:\Workbook2.xlsx")
Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Copy Value of wb1.ws1 and paste into wb2.ws2
ws1.Range("A1").Copy ws2.Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, and it doesn't seem to work. It gives me "Subscript out of range" on either "Set ws1 = wb1.WorkSheets("Sheet1")" or "Set ws2 = wb2.Worksheets("Sheet2")"

Comment: Then this workbooks do not have sheets with those names in them.